# TypeScript - destructing array after conversion with `as` operator causes compilation error: expression expected

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript 2.9.2.

A 3rd party library [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js) has a static method declared as:

```
joinPaths(...paths: (string | URI)[]): URI;
```

Now I have a variable named `urlPaths` declared as `urlPaths: string | string[]`, the following code is giving me error `[ts] Expression expected.` at the spread operator:

```
URI.joinPaths(typeof urlPaths === 'string' ? urlPaths as string : ...(urlPaths as string[]))
```

But if I extract the ternary operator expression out as a separate variable, it is fine:

```
const paths = typeof urlPaths === 'string' ? [urlPaths as string] : urlPaths as string[];
URI.joinPaths(...paths);
```

What's wrong with my syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread syntax is supported on arguments to functions, so your `...` should be at the outer most level:

```
URI.joinPaths(... (typeof urlPaths === 'string' ? [urlPaths as string] : (urlPaths as string[])));
```

But also note that the asserions are redundant, typescript will figure out the type without them since `typeof urlPaths === 'string'` is a type guard and `urlPaths: string | string[]`

```
URI.joinPaths(... (typeof urlPaths === 'string' ? [urlPaths] : urlPaths));
```